# class with union use of deleted function on constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, default-constructor, default-copy-constructor

I'm trying to make a class of a 4*4 matrix, it is built from an array of 16 floats, but I also want to represent it as an array of 4 vec4's (for each column).
The problem is it doesn't compile, and gives an error wherever I call mat4's constructor.
My mat4.h:

```
struct mat4 {

    union
    {
        float elements[4 * 4]; // column major ordering, index = row + col * 4
        vec4 columns[4];
    };

    mat4();
    mat4(float diagonal);

    mat4& mul(const mat4& other); //TODO: maybe return mat4
   // vec4 getColumn(int colIndex);
    static mat4 identity(); // construct and return an identity matrix
    static mat4 orthographic(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far); // boundaries (clipping planes)
    static mat4 perspective(float fov, float aspectRatio, float near, float far);
    static mat4 translation(const vec3& translation);
    static mat4 scale(const vec3 &scale);
    static mat4 rotation(float angle, const vec3 & axis);
    friend mat4 operator*(mat4 left, const mat4 & right);
    mat4& operator*=(const mat4 &other); //TODO: check that it fits with the vectors
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const mat4 &m);
};
```

My mat4.cpp:

```
#include "mat4.h"
        mat4::mat4() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4 * 4; i++)
                elements[i] = 0;
        }
        mat4::mat4(float diagonal) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4 * 4; ++i) {
                elements[i] = 0;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i += 1)
                elements[i + i * 4] = diagonal;
        }
        mat4& mat4::mul(const mat4 &other) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)        // col
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {  // row
                    float sum = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
                        sum += elements[j + k * 4] * other.elements[k + i * 4];
                    elements[j + i * 4] = sum;
                }
            return *this;
        }

        /*vec4 mat4::getColumn(int colIndex) {
            //colIndex *= 4; // TODO: profile and see if it's the same as (colIndex * 4) in each cell
            return vec4(elements[0 + colIndex * 4], elements[1 + colIndex * 4], elements[2 + colIndex * 4], elements[3 + colIndex * 4]);
        }*/
        mat4 mat4::identity() {
            return mat4(1.0f);
        }

        mat4 operator*(mat4 left, const mat4 &right) {
            return left.mul(right);
        }

        mat4 &mat4::operator*=(const mat4 &other) {
            return mul(other);
        }

        mat4 mat4::orthographic(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far) {
            mat4 result(1);
            result.elements[0 + 0 * 4] =  2.0f / (right - left);
            result.elements[1 + 1 * 4] =  2.0f / (top - bottom);
            result.elements[2 + 2 * 4] = -2.0f / (far - near);
            result.elements[0 + 3 * 4] = (left + right) / (left - right);
            result.elements[1 + 3 * 4] = (bottom + top) / (bottom - top);
            result.elements[2 + 3 * 4] = (far + near)   / (far - near);
            //result.elements[3 + 3 * 4] = 1; this is achieved by mat result(1);
            return result;
        }

        mat4 mat4::perspective(float fov, float aspectRatio, float near, float far) {
            mat4 result;

            float q = 1.0f / tanf(toRadians(fov) / 2.0f);
            result.elements[0 + 0 * 4] = q / aspectRatio;
            result.elements[1 + 1 * 4] = q;
            result.elements[2 + 2 * 4] = (near + far) / (near - far);   // -(far + near)  / (far - near);
            result.elements[3 + 2 * 4] = -1;
            result.elements[2 + 3 * 4] = 2 * far * near / (near - far); // -2 * far * near / (far - near);

            return result;
        }

        mat4 mat4::translation(const vec3 &translation) {
            mat4 result(1.0f); // identity matrix
            result.elements[0 + 3 * 4] = translation.x;     // create a matrix as follows: 1 0 0 x
            result.elements[1 + 3 * 4] = translation.y;     //                             0 1 0 y
            result.elements[2 + 3 * 4] = translation.z;     //                             0 0 1 z
            return result;                                  //                             0 0 0 1
        }

        mat4 mat4::scale(const vec3 &scale) {
            mat4 result(1.0f);
            result.elements[0 + 0 * 4] = scale.x;     // create a matrix as follows: x 0 0 0
            result.elements[1 + 1 * 4] = scale.y;     //                             0 y 0 0
            result.elements[2 + 2 * 4] = scale.z;     //                             0 0 z 0
            return result;                            //                             0 0 0 1
        }

        mat4 mat4::rotation(float angle, const vec3 &axis) {
            mat4 result(1.0f);
            float r = toRadians(angle);
            float s = sinf(r);
            float c = cosf(r);
            result.elements[0 + 0 * 4] = axis.x * (1 - c) + c;
            result.elements[1 + 0 * 4] = axis.x * axis.y * (1 - c) + axis.z * s;
            result.elements[2 + 0 * 4] = axis.x * axis.z * (1 - c) - axis.y * s;

            result.elements[0 + 1 * 4] = axis.y * axis.x * (1 - c) - axis.z * s;
            result.elements[1 + 1 * 4] = axis.y * (1 - c) + c;
            result.elements[2 + 1 * 4] = axis.y * axis.z * (1 - c) + axis.x * s;

            result.elements[0 + 2 * 4] = axis.z * axis.x * (1 - c) + axis.y * s;
            result.elements[1 + 2 * 4] = axis.z * axis.y * (1 - c) - axis.x * s;
            result.elements[2 + 2 * 4] = axis.z * (1 - c) + c;

            return result;
        }

        std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const mat4 &m) {
            stream << "mat4: ( ";
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                    stream << m.elements[i + j * 4] << " ";
                }
                if(i < 3) stream << std::endl << "        ";
                else stream << ")";
            }
            return stream;
        }
```

My vec4.h:

```
#include <iostream>

        struct vec4 {
            float w, x, y, z;

            vec4() = default; // declare a default constructor as a no-parameter constructor (given that I have another one)

            vec4(float w, float x, float y, float z);

            vec4(const vec4 &v);

            vec4 add(const vec4 &other); 
            vec4 add(float w, float x, float y, float z); 
            vec4 sub(const vec4 &other); 
            vec4 sub(float w, float x, float y, float z); 
            vec4 mul(const vec4 &other); 
            vec4 mul(float w, float x, float y, float z); 
            vec4 div(const vec4 &other); 
            vec4 div(float w, float x, float y, float z); 

            friend vec4 operator+(vec4 left, const vec4 &right);

            friend vec4 operator-(vec4 left, const vec4 &right);

            friend vec4 operator*(vec4 left, const vec4 &right);

            friend vec4 operator/(vec4 left, const vec4 &right);

            vec4 operator+=(const vec4 &other);

            vec4 operator-=(const vec4 &other);

            vec4 operator*=(const vec4 &other);

            vec4 operator/=(const vec4 &other);

            bool operator==(const vec4 &other);

            bool operator!=(const vec4 &other);

            friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const vec4 &vector);
        };
```

My vec4.cpp:

```
/*     vec4::vec4() {
            w = 0;
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            z = 0;
        }
*/
        vec4::vec4(float w, float x, float y, float z) {
            this->w = w;
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            this->z = z;
        }

        vec4::vec4(const vec4 &v) {
            this->w = v.w;
            this->x = v.x;
            this->y = v.y;
            this->z = v.z;
        }

        vec4 vec4::add(const vec4 &other) {
            this->w += other.w;
            this->x += other.x;
            this->y += other.y;
            this->z += other.z;
            return *this;
        }

        vec4 vec4::add(float w, float x, float y, float z) {
            this->w += w;
            this->x += x;
            this->y += y;
            this->z += z;
            return *this;
        }

        vec4 vec4::sub(const vec4 &other) {
            this->w -= other.w;
            this->x -= other.x;
            this->y -= other.y;
            this->z -= other.z;
            return *this;
        }

        vec4 vec4::sub(float w, float x, float y, float z) {
            this->w -= w;
            this->x -= x;
            this->y -= y;
            this->z -= z;
            return *this;
        }

        vec4 vec4::mul(const vec4 &other) {
            this->w *= other.w;
            this->x *= other.x;
            this->y *= other.y;
            this->z *= other.z;
            return *this;
        }

        vec4 vec4::mul(float w, float x, float y, float z) {
            this->w *= w;
            this->x *= x;
            this->y *= y;
            this->z *= z;
            return *this;
        }

        vec4 vec4::div(const vec4 &other) {
            this->w /= other.w;
            this->x /= other.x;
            this->y /= other.y;
            this->z /= other.z;
            return *this;
        }

        vec4 vec4::div(float w, float x, float y, float z) {
            this->w /= w;
            this->x /= x;
            this->y /= y;
            this->z /= z;
            return *this;
        }

        std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const vec4 &vector) {
            stream << "vec4: (" << vector.w << ", " << vector.x << ", " << vector.y << ", " << vector.z << ")";
            return stream;
        }

        vec4 operator+(vec4 left, const vec4 &right) {
            return left.add(right);
        }

        vec4 operator-(vec4 left, const vec4 &right) {
            return left.sub(right);
        }

        vec4 operator*(vec4 left, const vec4 &right) {
            return left.mul(right);
        }

        vec4 operator/(vec4 left, const vec4 &right) {
            return left.div(right);
        }

        vec4 vec4::operator+=(const vec4 &other) {
            return add(other);
        }

        vec4 vec4::operator-=(const vec4 &other) {
            return sub(other);

        }

        vec4 vec4::operator*=(const vec4 &other) {
            return mul(other);

        }

        vec4 vec4::operator/=(const vec4 &other) {
            return div(other);

        }

        bool vec4::operator==(const vec4 &other) {
            return (this->w == other.w && this->x == other.x && this->y == other.y && this->z == other.z);
        }

        bool vec4::operator!=(const vec4 &other) {
            return !(*this == other);
        }
```

And the error log:

```
.../src/math/mat4.cpp: In static member function ‘static engine::math::mat4 engine::math::mat4::identity()’:
.../src/math/mat4.cpp:36:29: error: use of deleted function ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(engine::math::mat4&&)’
             return mat4(1.0f);
                             ^
In file included from .../src/math/mat4.cpp:5:0:
.../src/math/mat4.h:11:16: note: ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(engine::math::mat4&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
         struct mat4 {
                ^
.../src/math/mat4.h:16:31: error: union member ‘engine::math::mat4::<anonymous union>::columns’ with non-trivial ‘engine::math::vec4::vec4(const engine::math::vec4&)’
                 vec4 columns[4];
                               ^
.../src/math/mat4.cpp: In function ‘engine::math::mat4 engine::math::operator*(engine::math::mat4, const engine::math::mat4&)’:
.../src/math/mat4.cpp:40:34: error: use of deleted function ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(const engine::math::mat4&)’
             return left.mul(right);
                                  ^
In file included from .../src/math/mat4.cpp:5:0:
.../src/math/mat4.h:11:16: note: ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(const engine::math::mat4&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
         struct mat4 {
                ^
.../src/math/mat4.h:16:31: error: union member ‘engine::math::mat4::<anonymous union>::columns’ with non-trivial ‘engine::math::vec4::vec4(const engine::math::vec4&)’
                 vec4 columns[4];
                               ^
.../src/math/mat4.cpp: In static member function ‘static engine::math::mat4 engine::math::mat4::orthographic(float, float, float, float, float, float)’:
.../src/math/mat4.cpp:56:20: error: use of deleted function ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(engine::math::mat4&&)’
             return result;
                    ^
.../src/math/mat4.cpp: In static member function ‘static engine::math::mat4 engine::math::mat4::perspective(float, float, float, float)’:
.../src/math/mat4.cpp:69:20: error: use of deleted function ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(engine::math::mat4&&)’
             return result;
                    ^
.../src/math/mat4.cpp: In static member function ‘static engine::math::mat4 engine::math::mat4::translation(const engine::math::vec3&)’:
.../src/math/mat4.cpp:77:20: error: use of deleted function ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(engine::math::mat4&&)’
             return result;                                  //                             0 0 0 1
                    ^
.../src/math/mat4.cpp: In static member function ‘static engine::math::mat4 engine::math::mat4::scale(const engine::math::vec3&)’:
.../src/math/mat4.cpp:85:20: error: use of deleted function ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(engine::math::mat4&&)’
             return result;                            //                             0 0 0 1
                    ^
.../src/math/mat4.cpp: In static member function ‘static engine::math::mat4 engine::math::mat4::rotation(float, const engine::math::vec3&)’:
.../src/math/mat4.cpp:105:20: error: use of deleted function ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(engine::math::mat4&&)’
             return result;
                    ^
CMakeFiles/GameEngine.dir/build.make:169: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/GameEngine.dir/src/math/mat4.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/GameEngine.dir/src/math/mat4.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
.../main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
.../main.cpp:19:50: error: use of deleted function ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(engine::math::mat4&&)’
     mat4 position = mat4::translation(vec3(2,3,4));
                                                  ^
In file included from .../src/math/math.h:8:0,
                 from .../main.cpp:4:
.../src/math/mat4.h:11:16: note: ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(engine::math::mat4&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
         struct mat4 {
                ^
.../src/math/mat4.h:16:31: error: union member ‘engine::math::mat4::<anonymous union>::columns’ with non-trivial ‘engine::math::vec4::vec4(const engine::math::vec4&)’
                 vec4 columns[4];
                               ^
```

I assume most of the code is irrelevant so don't bother reading all of it.
Just for comparison's sake, if I remove the link `vec4 columns[4];` from the union at mat4.h, then everything is fantastic.

I've been breaking my head at this for the past hour so I would really like some help.

Thanks.

EDIT:

After trying what @0x499602D2 suggested and also adding `mat4(mat4&&) = default;` to mat4.h, I only have one error remaining:

```
.../src/math/mat4.cpp: In function ‘engine::math::mat4 engine::math::operator*(engine::math::mat4, const engine::math::mat4&)’:
.../src/math/mat4.cpp:39:34: error: use of deleted function ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(const engine::math::mat4&)’
             return left.mul(right);
                                  ^
In file included from .../src/math/mat4.cpp:5:0:
.../src/math/mat4.h:11:16: note: ‘engine::math::mat4::mat4(const engine::math::mat4&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘engine::math::mat4’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
         struct mat4 {
                ^
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vec4` declares a copy-constuctor, so there is no implicit move-constructor generated for its class. Since you have an array of `vec4` inside your union, its move-constructor is deleted since `vec4`'s cannot be moved-from. Moreover, since `vec4` has a user-provided copy-constructor, it is considered non-trivial and thus the union's copy-constructor is deleted too. Since the union is a member of `mat4` (and the union has a deleted copy and move-constructor) `mat4`'s copy and move-constructor is deleted too.

Deleted functions still play a role in overload resolution so the deleted move-constructor is chosen since you are initializing your return value from a temporary. To fix this, declare a default move-constructor inside `vec4`:

```
struct vec4 {
    // ...
    vec4(vec4&&) = default;
    // ...
};
```

and a copy-constructor in `mat4`:

```
mat4(mat4 const&) {}
```

If you have any members that need to be copied you have to do it manually AFAIK.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question,  what is the difference between a copy-constructor and a move-constructor? I'm coming from a Java background and have no idea what a move constructor is...

Comment: @shoham The solution to your problem is to declare a move-constructor in `vec4`, see my edit.

Comment: I did that now, it doesn't seem to help, but if I also do the same for mat4: `mat4(mat4&&) = default;` I only have one error remaining, I'll edit my answer so it'll be more comfortable to see.

Comment: @shoham Sorry for the changes. Your copy-constructor needs to be `mat4(mat4 const&) {}`. If you have any members that need to be copied you have to do it manually.

Comment: Alright, now this works, but could you elaborate on all this defaulting? Why do I need to declare a new *empty* copy-constructor? What if for some reason I wanted to make a move-constructor?
What is the logic behind your advice?

Is that because I have a copy constructor in vec4? If so, why an empty one in mat4, or can I put stuff in it?

Comment: @shoham As a matter of fact, you don't need a move-constructor in `vec4`, get rid of it. All you need is the copy-constructor in `mat4`. The reason it is empty instead of `= default` is because the defaulted method would try to copy the union. The union can't be copied because it's copy-constructor is deleted because `vec4` declares its own copy-constructor (that's just the rules for unions). If you need to, you can use `mat4`'s copy-constructor to copy your members (but don't copy the union since it can't be copied!). To learn about move-constructors, see the link in my comment.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now, still pretty complex though. Thank you very much.

Comment: @shoham Don't worry about the details. Try using Serge's answer if it's easier to understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

0x499602D2's answer explains your error and answers the specific question you asked. But I think it is at least a strange design to store the matrix data in two possible ways. And your implementation is incoherent with it since in `mat4& mat4::mul(const mat4 &other)` (and other methods) you only use the `elements` part of the union.

IMHO you should considere to :

- replace the union with a simple `float elements[4 * 4];`
- add a constructor taking 4 `vec4` parameters and storing values into the `elements` array
- add a const method to extract the vectors from the matrix

Because it is much more common to define one single internal implementation and as many *external* representations as you want.

It does not directly answers your question (@0x499602D2 already did), but if you follow this advice, the problem will vanish, so this answer ...